# Are there any studies done on diaper usage from newborn to 2 years?

Tags: newborn, research, diaper

I found a lot of websites stating different amounts of disposable diaper changes per day for newborn to 2 year old's, but I can't find any reference to research or surveys done to back the numbers.

I've scoured Google Scholar but can't find any research papers on disposable diaper changing frequency there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Espinosa-Valdemar, Rosa & Vazquez, Alethia & Ojeda-Benitez, Sara & Arango-Escorcia, Gabriela & Cabrera-Elizalde, Sonia & Quecholac-Piña, Xochitl & Velasco Perez, Maribel & Sotelo Navarro, Perla Xochitl. (2015). Assessment of Gardening Wastes as a Co-Substrate for Diapers Degradation by the Fungus Pleurotus ostreatus. sustainability. 2015. 6033-6045. 10.3390/su7056033.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276294604_Assessment_of_Gardening_Wastes_as_a_Co-Substrate_for_Diapers_Degradation_by_the_Fungus_Pleurotus_ostreatus), figure 4:

[image]

- [Colón, Joan & Ruggieri, Luz & Sánchez, Antoni & González, Aina & Puig-Ventosa, Ignasi. (2011). Possibilities of composting disposable diapers with municipal solid wastes. Waste management & research : the journal of the International Solid Wastes and Public Cleansing Association, ISWA. 29. 249-59. 10.1177/0734242X10364684.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/43226690_Possibilities_of_composting_disposable_diapers_with_municipal_solid_wastes), table 4:

[image]

Found two studies that seem to both indicate an initial average of seven diapers per day, which over time decreases to around five diapers per day.